# Why the inner function used in below scala code , cant we write it without the inner function

Tags: scala, function, functional-programming, nested

```
def pack[A](l: List[A]):List[List[A]] = {
    def _pack(res: List[List[A]], rem: List[A]):List[List[A]] = rem match {
        case Nil => res
        case h::tail if (res.isEmpty || res.last.head != h) => _pack(res:::List(List(h)), tail)
        case h::tail => _pack(res.init:::List(res.last:::List(h)), tail)
    }
    _pack(List(),l)
}
```

Above code Packs consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists.

Comment: because this is what tail recursion is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner function seems just to be a design choice. Thanks to the usage of inner function it possible to close the whole implementation inside *pack[A]* scope. It would be absolutely valid to move *_pack* function outside (it would require to add a generic argument), however then would be possible to call it outside *pack[A]* scope.

This is another possible implementation of the mentioned function:

```
def pack[A](l: List[A]) : List[List[A]] = (l :\ List.empty[List[A]]){
    case (e, (acc@(hd::_))::tl) if hd == e => (e::acc)::tl
    case (e,  acc)                         => List(e)::acc
}
```